# Jenkins: How to get an encrypted credentials password from shell script?

Tags: bash, encryption, jenkins

I was using the secrets/master.key that was there when the password was encrypted and stored to credentials.xml. But restoring the the same set of credentials.xml and master.key is not working in a new jenkins setup. I even tried to restore secret.key but that too is not working.

I also noticed the ecrypted string in is credentials.xml is also not same for same string.
I am trying to automate the jenkins setup. Is there a way I can get the encrypted password that the jenkins produce from bash?

Answer (score 2):

Jenkins and its plugins usually encrypt strings using the `Secret` class, which (AFAICT) stores the key under `${JENKINS_HOME}/secrets/hudson.util.Secret`.

I don't know of any easy standalone solution, but you can use the Jenkins [Script Console](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Script+Console) (or the `groovy` [CLI](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/cli/) command) to attempt to decrypt secret values that you have:

```
import hudson.util.Secret

Secret a = Secret.fromString('my secret value')
String ciphertext = a.getEncryptedValue()
println ciphertext
// '{AQAAABAAAAAQdIQUuG2AhKoV7mCIcd3PXBdw8ItgchIrvQrQ=}'
// or similar; will change with each new secret object

Secret b = Secret.decrypt(ciphertext)
String plaintext = b.getPlainText()
println plaintext
// 'my secret value'
```

Comment: Can you tell us how?

Answer (score 1):

```
  host=http://$JENKINS_USERNAME:$JENKINS_PASSWORD@localhost:8080
 CRUMB=$(curl -s "$host"'/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,":",//crumb)')
 encrypted_passphrase=$(curl  -H "$CRUMB" -d "script=println(hudson.util.Secret.fromString('password').getEncryptedValue())" -X POST $host/scriptText)
```